# Playwright: How to handle long-loading ads preventing DOMContentLoaded event from firing during page navigation?

Tags: java, playwright, playwright-java

I'm using Playwright Java version 1.28.1 to test my company's website. I'm trying to navigate to the website using the following code:

```
page.waitForLoadState(LoadState.DOMCONTENTLOADED);
page.navigate("https://my-company-website.com/");
```

The problem is that the website also loads ads at the same time as the main app, and sometimes these ads take a long time to load. This prevents the DOMContentLoaded event from firing, and I get a TimeoutError:

```
com.microsoft.playwright.TimeoutError: Error { message='Timeout 30000ms exceeded. 
=========================== logs =========================== 
navigating to "https://my-company-website.com/", waiting until "load".
```

Is there a way to fix this error? Can I tell Playwright to not wait for the page to fully load? Or can I trigger the page load as soon as a specific HTML DOM element becomes visible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Playwright for Java, but in other language implementations, such as Playwright for JavaScript, usually you only navigate rather than waiting for a load state before a navigation. In JS, the following usually fails because of the extra wait:

```js
// usually wrong
await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
await page.goto("https://www.example.com", {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
```

or

```js
// usually wrong
await page.goto("https://www.example.com", {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
```

Try making a single call to `navigate` and specify the `setWaitUntil` option to determine which load state the `navigate` call should block until.

For example:

```java
// removed waitForLoadState
page.navigate(
    "https://example.com",
    new Page.NavigateOptions()
        .setWaitUntil(WaitUntilState.DOMCONTENTLOADED)
);
```

Ads shouldn't prevent the DOM loaded event from firing, but if they do, it'd be useful to see the actual site so the behavior can be understood and dealt with. A typical solution is to block requests that run the ad scripts. It's generally a good idea to block any unneeded resources for performance reasons anyway.